# fatal error: Index out of range search for an item

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, swift4

I have contrl segments and UITableview. The table reloads depending on the segment selected or the search performed. The control segment is working fine but the search is not working. When I try to type anything in the bar it reloads only and when I click on the cell it crashes. Can someone help me here? Thank you so much

```
   var auxiliar: [Shops]? = [Shops]()
   var searchActive: Bool = false    
// shops category
   var restuarnt = [Shops]()
   var coffee = [Shops]()
   var pharmacy = [Shops]()
   var supermarket = [Shops]()
   var home = [Shops]()
   var clothes = [Shops]()
   var allShops  = [Shops]()    
   var shops = [Shops]()

   var selectedIndex = 0



s.valueChange = { index in

            if index == 0 {

                self.selectedIndex = 0
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
            if index == 1 {
                self.selectedIndex = 1

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            if index == 2 {
                self.selectedIndex = 2

            }
            if index == 3 {

                self.selectedIndex = 3

            }



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if selectedIndex == 0 {
            return  allShops.count

        }
        if selectedIndex == 1 {

            return self.coffee.count
        }
        if selectedIndex == 2 {

            return self.restuarnt.count
        }
        if selectedIndex == 3 {

            return self.pharmacy.count
        }

        if searchActive {
            return auxiliar!.count
        }else{
            return   allShops.count

        }

    }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if selectedIndex == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell

        let entry = shops[indexPath.row]

        cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.Logo))
        cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
        cell.star.rating = Double(entry.rate)
        cell.time.text = entry.time


        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
        return cell
    }

    if selectedIndex ==  1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell

        let entry = coffee[indexPath.row]

        cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.Logo))
        cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
        cell.star.rating = Double(entry.rate)
        cell.time.text = entry.time


        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
        return cell
    }

    if selectedIndex ==  2 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell

        let entry = restuarnt[indexPath.row]

        cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.Logo))
        cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
        cell.star.rating = Double(entry.rate)
        cell.time.text = entry.time


        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
        return cell
    }
    if selectedIndex ==  3 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell

        let entry = pharmacy[indexPath.row]

        cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.Logo))
        cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
        cell.star.rating = Double(entry.rate)
        cell.time.text = entry.time


        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
        return cell
    }

    if searchActive

    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
        let entry1 = auxiliar?[indexPath.row]


        cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: (entry1?.Logo)!))
        cell.shopName.text = entry1?.shopname

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
        cell.time.text = entry1?.time

        cell.star.rating = Double((entry1?.rate)!)
        return cell
    }
    else {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell

        let entry = shops[indexPath.row]

        cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.Logo))
        cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
        cell.star.rating = Double(entry.rate)
        cell.time.text = entry.time


        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
        return cell

    }
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if selectedIndex == 1 {
            let meal1 =  coffee[indexPath.row]


            guard (coffee.count) > indexPath.row else {
                print("Index out of range")
                return
            }

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! MealsDetailsController
            viewController.passedValue = (meal1.familiy_id)
            viewController.name = (meal1.shopname)

            print("\(meal1.familiy_id) im the search ")
            view.animateRandom()
            self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)



        }
        if selectedIndex == 0 {
            let meal1 =  shops[indexPath.row]


            guard (shops.count) > indexPath.row else {
                print("Index out of range")
                return
            }

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! MealsDetailsController
            viewController.passedValue = (meal1.familiy_id)
            viewController.name = (meal1.shopname)

            print("\(meal1.familiy_id) im the search ")
            view.animateRandom()
            self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)



        }
        if selectedIndex == 2 {
            let meal1 =  restuarnt[indexPath.row]


            guard (restuarnt.count) > indexPath.row else {
                print("Index out of range")
                return
            }

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! MealsDetailsController
            viewController.passedValue = (meal1.familiy_id)
            viewController.name = (meal1.shopname)

            print("\(meal1.familiy_id) im the search ")
            view.animateRandom()
            self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)



        }
        if selectedIndex == 3 {
            let meal1 =  pharmacy[indexPath.row]


            guard (pharmacy.count) > indexPath.row else {
                print("Index out of range")
                return
            }

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! MealsDetailsController
            viewController.passedValue = (meal1.familiy_id)
            viewController.name = (meal1.shopname)

            print("\(meal1.familiy_id) im the search ")
            view.animateRandom()
            self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)



        }

        if searchActive {
            let meal1 =  auxiliar?[indexPath.row]


            guard (auxiliar?.count)! > indexPath.row else {
                print("Index out of range")
                return
            }

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! MealsDetailsController
            viewController.passedValue = (meal1?.familiy_id)!
            viewController.name = (meal1?.shopname)!

            print("\(meal1?.familiy_id) im the search ")
          view.animateRandom()
            self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)




        } else {
            let meal =  shops[indexPath.row]


            guard shops.count > indexPath.row else {
                print("Index out of range")
                return
            }

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! MealsDetailsController
            viewController.passedValue = meal.familiy_id
            viewController.name = meal.shopname
            view.animateRandom()
            self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)


        }

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        auxiliar = shops.filter { $0.shopname.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil}
        if searchText == "" || searchBar.text == nil {
            auxiliar = shops
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

The crash is cause by this line `let meal1 =  auxiliar?[indexPath.row]`

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Unrelated, but instead of the separate `if` clauses without `else` branches, you should be using `switch` statements to make your code more readable.

Comment: `let meal1 =  auxiliar?[indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 1):

You should exchange the following two statements:

```
let meal1 = auxiliar?[indexPath.row]
guard (auxiliar?.count)! > indexPath.row else {
    print("Index out of range")
    return
}
```

It makes no sense to try the subscripting (which will result in an exception if `auxiliar.count <= indexPath.row`) and after that check if the subscripting is actually safe.

It should be:

```
guard auxiliar.count > indexPath.row else {
    print("Index out of range")
    return
}
let meal1 = auxiliar[indexPath.row]
```

Moreover, `var auxiliar: [Shops]? = [Shops]()` makes no sense. If you provide a default value to `auxiliar`, why define it as `Optional`? Just simply declare `auxiliar` as a non-optional by `var auxiliar = [Shops]()`.

Moreover, you should revisit your implementation of `tableView(:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, since you are checking two different variables to determine what value to return, which can easily cause problems if you don't reset `selectedIndex`, since in that case the function can never reach the `if searchActive` part.

You should also refactor your code and use `switch` statements instead of several `if` statements with distinct conditions and no `else` branches.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I did fix it and it's not crashing now but the result of the search isnt correct

Comment: I added `textDidChange` in my question please see how I coded it